# Matrix multiplication and determinant question

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $\det(\begin{bmatrix}b & c\\a & b\end{bmatrix})=0$ with  $A=\begin{bmatrix}a & a\\b & b\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}b & b\\c & c\end{bmatrix}$ then $AB=BA.$

How do I go by solving this? I tried finding the determent, $AB$, and $BA$ but it didn't work.

Comment: if you use $b^2=ac$ then it should be fine

Answer (score 3):

We have that 
\begin{equation*}
AB = 
\begin{bmatrix}
ab & ac \\
bb & bc
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and

\begin{equation*}
BA = 
\begin{bmatrix}
ba & bb \\
ca & cb
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

and from our determinant result we know $bb - ca = 0$, or equivalently $bb = ca$, so then our result clearly follows after substituting one for the other in both $AB$ and $BA$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & a \\ b & b \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} b & b \\ c & c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ab+ac & ab+ac \\ c^2+bc & b^2 + bc \end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} b & b \\ c & c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & a \\ b & b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ab+b^2 & ab+b^2 \\ ac+bc & ac + bc \end{bmatrix} 
$$

So we ask whether $ab+ac$ is the same as $ab+b^2$.  They're the same if $ac=b^2$.  That happens if $b^2-ac=0$.  And $b^2-ac$ is the determinant that you mentioned.  So check the other three entries in the same way.